# CSS colour styles depending on returned Ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to change my error status CSS for when an error is returned from my PHP.

I thought I might be able to add `.css({'background-color':'red'})` to the error function as shown below but this doesn't work.

There maybe a better what I can call a class and set a list of styles in my CSS ?

Currently my success and error returns alert-primary I would like error to return as alert-danger but I am not sure how to separate the two.

```js
function validateForm() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "register.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#registration-form').serialize(),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#status').text(data.message);
            if (data.code) //If mail was sent successfully, reset the form.
                $('#registration-form').closest('form').find("input[type=text],textarea").val("");},
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#status').text(jqXHR).css({ 'background-color': 'red' });
        }
    });

}
```

```html
<div class="alert hide" role="alert hide">
    <div class=" alert-primary">
        <div class="status" id="status"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you _completely_ changed the nature of your question _after_ you've gotten answers, I rolled it backed to before those changes. _Don't change the question_ after it's been posted. That's like moving the goal post and will make any answers invalid and confusing for future visitors. If you get stuck on something new, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use proper CSS classes for this.

Add the following CSS class in your CSS-file:

```
.error {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then you just add that class on the element instead of inline CSS:

```
$('#status').addClass('error').text(...the message...);
```

Now you've separated your concerns.

Comment: I have set it up so that I now have a css for both error and success but I am only getting error displaying.

Comment: $.ajax({
url : "register.php",
type: "POST",
data :$('#registration-form').serialize(),
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#status').addClass("successCSS").text(data.message);
    $('#status').addClass("errorCSS").text(data.errormessage);
    if (data.code) //If mail was sent successfully, reset the form.
    $('#registration-form').closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
    $('#status').text(jqXHR);

}
});

Comment: Why are you adding both `successCSS` and `errorCSS` in the success-callback? If both classes are setting the the same css-properties, then only the values from the last (`errorCSS`) will be used.

Comment: Because it seems that all messages are going through that class..... the success: function is also displaying the error messages. I noticed that when I added the css class to the $('#status').addClass("successCSS").text(data.message); and set it to yellow it displayed both error and success to yellow.

Comment: @Hutch - Just check if the parameter `errormessage` or `message` exists in the response and set the correct class. Also, you've just updated your question to be totally different than the first question. **Don't do that**. If you have another question, write it as another question. This answer answered your first question. Don't move the goal post.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your php output?
It would be easier to style, and you don't need to change your front-end code, try adding a class instead pure CSS.